# Once you remove an app from iOS notification center, can you add it back?

Tags: ios, ipod-touch

I exited out of my snapchat notifications in the notification center (I clicked the "x" on the right hand side) and now I can't see anything and I want to get it back.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Is this about Notification Center on Mac or something on an iPod touch? Your question sounds like a Mac question (what with clicking an x), but you have it tagged ipod-touch.

Comment: It's about an ipod touch... the "x" being the little close-out button... because there's an "x" on it

Comment: Note that this does not remove the specific notification, but removes the entire app from Notification Center.

Answer (score 1):

Nope you can't get it back once you dismissed the notification.

Comment: Note that this is not about the notification itself, but about _all_ notifications of the specific app.

Answer (score 0):

I did this to a couple apps, and then realised my mistake. So far, I have only been able to restore the application to the notification screen by completely removing it and all its configurations (through General > Usage > *app name*), but that is far from ideal.

I'm very interested in a better solution.